# multiple templates in one module magento

Tags: templates, magento

I have two template files in `design/frontend/default/template/lookbook/`, **lookbook.phtml** and **lookbookpage.phtml.** I want to call **lookbookpage.phtml** template from **lookbook.phtml**, something like:

```
<h4><?php echo $this->__('Lookbook') ?></h4>
<?php
$lookbooks = Mage::getModel('manager/manager')->getCollection(); 
foreach ( $lookbooks as $lookbook ): ?>
    <a href=""><?php echo $lookbook->getTitle(); ?></a><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I don't know what to write in `<a href="" />` to go to lookbookpage.phtml template.
My design/frontend/default/layout/lookbook.xml looks like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    </default>
    <manager_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="manager/manager" name="manager" template="lookbook/lookbook.phtml" />
        </reference>        
    </manager_index_index>
</layout>
```

I don't know what I need to do in my layout xml file. I just need a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <manager_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="manager/manager" name="manager" template="lookbook/lookbook.phtml">
                <block type="manager/manager" name="manager_page" template="lookbook/lookbookpage.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>        
    </manager_index_index>
</layout>
```

And in your **lookbook.phtml** use `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('manager_page') ?>`.

I wonder about the block types you are using though; it would be highly unusual to use a block instance inside itself.  If you simply need to render a template, just use `Mage_Core_Block_Template` i.e. `type="core/template"`.

Comment: Thanks Ben... However, how can I pass the id from lookbook.phtml to lookbookpage.phtml?

Comment: Ah, I see where you're going. You'll want a view class (block) to loop through the collection items and render them. See e.g. the `checkout/cart.phtml` template - look for the `getItems()` loop and the method used inside to render each product. Another approach would be to not use a child block, as is this case with `catalog/product/list.phtml` template.

Comment: I am able to call the block function for collection but still don't understand how to render the html and make it a link so that it calls lookbookpage template from lookbook.phtml